# extract package: stop extraction at specific point

Tags: extract

I use the `extract` package to extract an outline from my main document. I don't want anything of the appendix included in the outline, so I'm searching for any way to set the `active` option to inactive after the main text.

Is there any way to stop the extraction for everything from a certain point on?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\let\synopsis\comment
\let\endsynopsis\endcomment
\usepackage[active,
    generate=synopsis,
    extract-env={synopsis},
    extract-cmd={section},
]{extract}
\begin{extract}
    \newenvironment{synopsis}{}{}
\end{extract}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{synopsis}
here something for the synopsis
\end{synopsis}

\section{Section2}
here something for the main document

% Start appendix here
\begin{extractskip} % this doesn't do anything
\section{I dont want this in the synopsis}
\begin{synopsis}
This neither
\end{synopsis}
\end{extractskip}
\end{document}
```

The `extractskip` doesn't work here but this is basically what I would need. Or something like `extract = false` to suppress extraction from this point onwards...

Comment: According to the documentation, there is the `extractskip` environment.

Comment: that's right, but it doesn't work for the commands defined in `extract-cmd`

Comment: A small example?

Comment: I added an example... hope that helps to clarify